# Data validation: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to validate a column in excel through the following code:

```
for i in range(1, len(risk_1)):
    worksheet.data_validation('B' + i, {'validate': 'list',
                                        'source': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']})
```

As you can see I can't add up the string and the i, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: `str(i)` should solve it. You cannot add an integer directly to a string

Comment: `i` is integer, so try making it to `str(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concacenate (add), they need to be of the same type.

`B` is a string, while `i` is an integer, generated from iterating through a range object.

You will need to cast `i` to a string, by doing `str(i)`